# MySQL Limit Rows Bug

Tags: php, mysql, limit, offset

```
SELECT * FROM `news` 
WHERE `deleted` = '0' 
ORDER BY `time` DESC 
LIMIT $START, $END
```

When `LIMIT` = `0,10` it loads good.
When `LIMIT` is `10,20` it loads good.
When `LIMIT` is `20,30` it loads the last 4 rows already shown in `20,30` again...

Comment: how many rows you have in table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way you're using `LIMIT` is incorrect. It's not,

```
LIMIT <start> <end>
```

but rather,

```
LIMIT <offset> <number_of_rows>
```

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html),

> The first argument specifies the
>   offset of the first row to return, and
>   the second specifies the maximum
>   number of rows to return.

So for example,

```
... LIMIT 0, 10 -- first 10 rows
... LIMIT 10, 10 -- rows 10-20
... LIMIT 10, 20 -- rows 10-30, not 10-20
... LIMIT 20, 30 -- rows 20-50, not 20-30
```

If you don't have enough rows in the resultset to fill the limit, it will just return up to the last row. For example, if you only retrieve 15 rows, `...LIMIT 10, 10` would return rows 10-15.

Comment: Don't blame yourself I just spent 30 minutes fooling around as well. This is what happens when you don't read instructions in detail. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html:

> SELECT ... FROM single_table ... ORDER BY non_index_column [DESC]
>   LIMIT [M,]N;
>
> Return the first N rows from the queue. (If M was specified, skip the
>   first M rows and return the next N rows.)

- LIMIT 0, 10              -- first 10 rows, rows 1-10
- LIMIT 10, 10             -- rows 11-20
- LIMIT 10, 20             -- rows 11-30, not 11-20
- LIMIT 20, 30             -- rows 21-50, not 21-30

Answer (score -2):

First fetch Full data from DB using 
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM [table name];
it return total count;

use Three variable;

$start
$end;
$total_records;

use ceil($total_records/$start);
U ll get roundValue;
use it limit